# How to get memory address of a variable or list element in kdb

Tags: kdb

How can we get the memory address of a variable or list in q?
I have below variable and list and I want to get their memory address.

```
a:10
l:1 2 3
```

What we looking for is something similar to id() in python

```
l=[1,2,3]
[id(i) for i in l] #[33849672L, 33849648L, 33849624L], sequence being address of first element is at the end

a="abc"
print(id(a)) #47382360
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done, unless you write custom native methods and bind them to Q.